# Changing the array contents of creating a modified array conditionally

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have the following code which searches the sheets named 1 to 12 in the workbook, and creates two sheets if Sheets from 1 to 12 are found. It takes into account the error if the any of the sheets between 1 to 12 are not present. Everytime one or many sheets can be absent from 1 to 12. Is it possible for me to create another array or change the array contents which will only contain the numbers corresponding to the sheets which are present in the workbook so that I can use this modified array in all the other codes to be applied to those sheets. Kindly suggest a code with which a new modified array can be created of only the existing sheets among 1 to 12.

```
Sub add_sheets()
Dim MyArr, j As Long
Dim wsarray As Sheets
Dim ws As Worksheet

MyArr = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12")

For j = 0 To UBound(MyArr)
Set ws = Nothing

On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Worksheets(MyArr(j))
On Error GoTo 0
If Not ws Is Nothing Then

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=ws, Count:=2
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 2).Activate

Else
Err.Clear
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you need the array for? Why couldn't you just loop through all existing sheets?

Comment: The concrete version of @Raystafarian's suggestion: `For Each ws in Worksheets`.  Then you don't have to worry about what is/is not missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary is convenient way to keep the list of worksheets

Added benefits of having both sheet Indexes, sheet Names, and Exists Method

This code uses the suggestion in the comments in Sub SetWorksheets() without triggering errors:

```
Option Explicit   'Add reference to: Tools -> References -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Public Sub AddSheets()
    Dim wsList As Dictionary
    Dim activeWs As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set activeWs = wb.ActiveSheet
        Set wsList = New Dictionary:            'wsList.CompareMode = BinaryCompare
        SetWorksheets wsList
        TestWorksheets wsList, "Initial Worksheets"
        While wsList.Count < 12
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
            With ws
                wsList.Add Key:=.Index, Item:=.Name
            End With
        Wend
        TestWorksheets wsList, "Final Worksheets"
        DelWorksheets
        activeWs.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Sub SetWorksheets(ByRef wsLst As Dictionary, _
                         Optional ByRef wb As Workbook = Nothing)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        With ws
            wsLst.Add Key:=.Index, Item:=.Name  'Or: d.Add Key:=.Name, Item:=.Index
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

A note, as it may not be very obvious: SetWorksheets() is a Sub and not a Function because the first parameter is passed ByRef and this implies, among other things, that it will be changed inside the Sub. As a result the initial object sent to this sub will also be updated

To test it:

```
Public Sub TestWorksheets(ByRef wsLst As Dictionary, txt As String)
    Dim itm As Variant, msg As String
    msg = txt & ": " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    For Each itm In wsLst
        With itm
            msg = msg & vbTab & itm & ": " & vbTab & wsLst.Item(itm) & vbCrLf
        End With
    Next
    MsgBox msg & vbCrLf & "Sheet 5 exists: " & vbTab & wsLst.Exists(5)
End Sub

Public Sub DelWorksheets()
    Dim itm As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each itm In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If itm.Index > 3 Then itm.Delete
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]